# Mysql get first date and last date from column and make 2 seperated columns as result

Tags: mysql

I have for example a column with dates, see below. Now a want to make a query with as result see below.

How can i achieve that?

Table:

```
id dates
1  2018-02-02, 2018-02-03, 2018-02-04, 2018-02-05
```

Desired result:

```
id dates                                          startdate  enddate
1  2018-02-02, 2018-02-03, 2018-02-04, 2018-02-05 2018-02-02 2018-02-05
```

Comment: Do not store values as csv. Read about one to many relationships. Also store Dates as date type not as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `date` is a `VARCHAR` and that it is sorted in ascending order, so use [MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) as shown below:

```
SELECT id, `date`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`date`, ".", 1) startdate,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(`date`, ".", -1) enddate
FROM `Table`;
```

It's advisable to always store date values as date.